# Is there a structured data type or Microformat for interviews?

Tags: structured-data, microformats

Does anyone know of a good structured data type (e.g., a Microformat) for marking up interviews?

At the moment I think I am going to fall back to Schema.org’s `Event`, but would love to know if there is currently a better standard for one somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a microformat specifically for interviews, but you could combine [definition lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-xhtml2-20040722/mod-list.html#sec_11.1.) (with the question as the term, the answer as the description) with Google's [author markup](http://searchengineland.com/google-adds-authorship-rich-snippet-markup-80455).

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any that I can find. But even if there were, it doesn't mean the search engines will honor it. If the microformat isn't listed at schema.org, which is honored by all of the major search engines, then it isn't standard and there is no reason to believe it will be used by them.

Comment: Microformats are not just for search engines, although certainly I would always follow what the big 3 say as a general rule.